# Why is my jQuery click handler not firing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2010

I've got this HTML in the *WebPartUserControl.ascx file of my Sharepoint 2010 Web Part project:

```
<html>
  <h1>Pre- and Post Travel Form Help</h1>
  <div id="preTravel" name="preTravel">
    <h2>Pre Travel</h2>
    <img id="imgPreTravel" name="imgPreTravel" src="/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png" alt="pre Travel image" height="275" width="350">
  </div>
  <div id="postTravel" name="postTravel">
    <h2>Post Travel</h2>
    <img id="imgPostTravel" name="imgPostTravel" src="/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png" alt="post Travel image" height="275" width="350">
  </div>
</html>
```

...and this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('imgPostTravel').click(function () {
        alert('you clicked the post Travel image');
        this.addClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

The pertinent CSS is:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

When I click 'imgPostTravel', though, nothing happens - not only does the image not disappear, I don't see the alert.

As a sanity check (which I'm possibly failing), I tried similar code in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/n9sq7x8y/) and *there, too* the click handler is not firing - there must be something fundamentally daft about what I'm doing, but I can't see it...

Comment: you need to use `$('#imgPreTravel')` instead of `$('imgPreTravel')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple fix, just add a hashtag to your selector since it's an ID:

```
$('#imgPostTravel').click(function () {
```

Comment: Crap, I can't believe I forgot that again; somebody kick me (not a good thing).

Comment: Always good to get another set of eyes! Please click the tick mark on the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#imgPostTravel').click(function () {
                alert('you clicked the post Travel image');
                this.addClass('hide');
            });
        });
</script>
```